# In rails is there a difference between mysite/show/1.js and mysite/show/1.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

In my rails 3 app, if I want a request to return json data does it matter if I use

```
mysite/show/1.js
```

or

```
mysite/show/1.json
```

I know it seems obvious to use the json version but in my responses they look the same to me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: It depends on the way you implement the `respond_to` block.

- With `1.json` it should be clear that it delivers data as JSON.
- `1.js` could return Javascript that is evaluated by the page that requested it. In the early Rails/Ajax days this used to be done with RJS templates. See http://www.codyfauser.com/2005/11/20/rails-rjs-templates